Using MongoKitten on Xcode 16.0 to connect to localhost on Mac Sequoia results in Operation not permitted
On a Mac I am running a MongoDB instance in terminal. Which I start with:
brew services start mongodb-community@7.0
Then call mongosh
In terminal using show dbs I can see the database and then calling db.my_database.findOne() I can see that it has entries.
Using:
MongoKitten 7.9.4 
MacOS 15.0.1
Xcode 16.0
I then have built a Mac app in Xcode and I'm trying to connect to the localhost, Like so:
func connect() async {
    let connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/my_database"
    let db = try? await MongoDatabase.connect(to: connectionString)
}

I have also tried with:
let connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database"
Each time I run the Mac app, when I call the connect function above I get the error message:
socket(PF_SYSTEM, SOCK_DGRAM, SYSPROTO_CONTROL) failed: Operation not permitted
The dependencies look like:

I can't seem to find what else needs to be done to get this working. Can anyone help?
